# Why the bullseye code coverage doesn't trace a pure virtual function of inherited class?

Tags: c++, bullseye

I met a problem about the Bullseye code coverage. It's a tracing ability of the program.
The following code is not traced.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual void func()
    {
         std::cout << "Am I traced?" << std::endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    A *pa = new B;
    pa->func();
}
```

I guess that Bullseye may not trace pure virtual function. If there are someone who has a knowledge about the program, please give me some advice.

Comment: That doesn't compile. `class` is not a type; did you mean `auto`?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 errors, in the given program:

```
void func() = 0;
```

should be,

```
virtual void func() = 0;
```

And,

```
class *pa = new B;
```

should be,

```
class B *pa = new B;  // `class` keyword not needed
```

Also, note that `A` and `B` are not related (no inheritance).